# angular service.component error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Object>

Tags: angular, subscribe

I'm trying to learn angular by creating a web application for the parish.
in the `products-list.component.ts` I have the method for deleting which seems to be formally correct, but in the phase of `npm start` it goes into error with the error code

**TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise '.**

I apologize if I do not respect the formal rules for forwarding the problem, but I am new and maybe I am documenting the problem incorrectly.
Thanks for your patience.
Moreno

goes wrong on the `onDelete` method

in other classes I use similar code and I haven't had an error of this kind.
Are there any imports on list.component-products?
Thanks inifinite

```
import { Component, OnInit, SystemJsNgModuleLoader } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';


import { Prodotti } from 'src/app/model/prodotti.model';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';

import { ProdottiListService} from 'src/app/features/prodotti/components/prodotti-list/prodotti-list.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';



let Header_Msg = "Gestione Prodotti";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-prodotti-list',
  templateUrl: './prodotti-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prodotti-list.component.css']
})
export class ProdottiListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: ProdottiListService, private toastr: ToastrService) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.refreshList();
  }

  populateForm(emp: Prodotti) {
    this.service.formData = Object.assign({}, emp);
  }

  onDelete(id: number) {

    if (confirm('Confermi la cancellazione del Record ?'))  {
        this.service.deleteProdotti(id).subscribe(res => {
          this.service.refreshList();
          this.toastr.warning('Cancellazione eseguita con successo', Header_Msg);
        })
    }
  }

}
```

ERROR in src/app/features/prodotti/components/prodotti-list/prodotti-list.component.ts(41,41): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise'.

Comment: `subscribe()` is only for `Observable<T>`. You can use `.then()` for a promise instead of `subscribe()`. That being said you should probably share the code for `ProdottiListService`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the service method returns an `Observable` **not** a `promise`.

In your case `ProdottiListService` has `deleteProdotti` which returns a `promise` so you should be using  `.then(..)` not `.subscribe()`.

Either update your service method to return an `observable` or do not use `.subscribe` in component:

```
this.service.deleteProdotti(id).then(res => {
          this.service.refreshList();
          this.toastr.warning('Cancellazione eseguita con successo', Header_Msg);
        })
```

Comment: hello nircraft
Thank you for your contribution.
I certainly make a fundamental mistake and I don't realize the problem.
I would like to try to understand, thanks to your help, the mistake I make to avoid repeating myself in the future.
Obviously I'm new in this forum too.
I wanted to ask you if I can, in this context, attach in OneDrive, the project with the code of the classes that do not produce results from reading the data in the database and a clearer explanation of my problems.
It could certainly be a quicker form to clarify the problem.

Comment: @AaBb, np. hope it solved your problem. If so please accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: I thank you for your kind reply.
I have not solved the problem and I would like to be able to send you the project to help me understand where I am wrong.
I am a beginner and it would be important to set the code correctly.
Thank you.
Hello
Moreno